# Passing Response data to chartjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

I want to pass this json response data to a chartjs horizontal bar using angular
this is the response :

```json
Response: [
{
Description: "Prima Fase"
Id: 49
Items: [
 {Id: -1, Description: "Nessun Canale", Number: 7},
 {Id: 5, Description: "Altro Canale", Number: 3},
 {Id: 21, Description: "Collaboratore Enzo", Number: 1}
},
{
Description: "Seconda Fase"
Id: 70
Items: [
{Id: -1, Description: "Nessun Canale", Number: 3},
{Id: 3, Description: "Web", Number: 3},
{Id: 5, Description: "Altro Canale", Number: 3},
{Id: 27, Description: "15C", Number: 1},
]
}
]
```

I tried this using x axes and z axes of the horizontal bar of chart js using this code

```js
 getDataForFunnel() {
    this.barChartData = [];
    this.barChartLabels = [];
    this.funnelService.getFunnelGraph(this.funnelForm.value).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.currentResponseItems = response.Response.Items || [];
        this.funnelService.allDatasFunnel = response.Response.Items || [];
        this.currentResponseMessage = response.Response.Message;
        if (this.currentResponseItems) {
          this.currentResponseItems.forEach((y) =>
            this.barChartLabels.push(y.Description)
          );

          let array = [];
          this.currentResponseItems.forEach((x) => {
            array.push(x.Id);
          })
      
             this.currentResponseItems.forEach((x) => {
            x.Items.forEach((z) => {
             // console.log(z.Id)
              z["phaseId"] = x.Id;
              let zData = [];

              let number = array.indexOf(z.phaseId);
              if (z.Number != 0) {
               
                zData[number] = z.Number;  
                this.barChartData.push({
                  data: zData,
                  stack: "a",
                  label: z.Description,
                  idStatoAffiliazione: x.Id,
                  channelID: z.Id,
                });
                
            
              }
            })
          });
```

But it seems it doesont work because i alwyas have duplication with different colors like this:
i want to regroupe each canal with diffrent phases in order to eliminate duplications in the chart and give them the same color in each phase
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8AzU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this code where I remove the duplicates for legend items.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

function getRandomRgb() {
  var num = Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random());
  var r = num >> 16;
  var g = (num >> 8) & 255;
  var b = num & 255;
  return 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  barChartData: any[] = [];

  barChartLabels: any[] = [];

  barChartOptions: any;

  utenti: any[] = [];
  funnelTypes: any[] = [];
  chart: any = [];
  Id: any;
  Items = [];

  funnelForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    UserId: new FormControl(),
    GraphType: new FormControl(),
  });

  // graphLegendConfig: LabelConfig[] = [];
  graphColors: any[] = [];

  public currentResponseItems: any[];
  public currentResponseMessage: string;

  allSubs: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    const $this = this;
    this.barChartOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      tooltips: { enabled: false },
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'top',
        align: 'center',
        labels: {
          generateLabels: (chart) =>
            chart.data.datasets
              .map((ds, i) => {
                return {
                  text: ds.label,
                  datasetIndex: i,
                  fillStyle: chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor,
                  strokeStyle: chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor,
                  hidden: chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden,
                };
              })
              .filter((ds, i) => {
                return (
                  chart.data.datasets.findIndex((x) => ds.text === x.label) ===
                  ds.datasetIndex
                );
              }),
        },
        onClick: function (event, legendItem, legend) {
          console.log('click', this);
          const mappedData = this.chart.data.datasets.map((x, i) => ({
            index: i,
            label: x.label,
          }));
          console.log(mappedData);
          const filteredData = mappedData.filter(
            (x) => x.label === legendItem.text
          );
          console.log(filteredData);
          const swapped = !this.chart.getDatasetMeta(legendItem.datasetIndex)
            .hidden;
          filteredData.forEach((x) => {
            this.chart.getDatasetMeta(x.index).hidden = swapped;
          });
          this.chart.update();
        },
      },
      stackColumn: 'Description',
      borderColor: '#0F0F0F',
      borderWidth: 2,
      plugin: [],
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          display: true,
          align: 'center',
          anchor: 'center',
          color: '#000000',
          textStrokeColor: 'white',
          textShadowBlur: 2,
          textShadowColor: '#FFFFFF',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold',
            size: 18,
          },
          formatter: (value) => {
            return value > 0 ? value : '';
          },
        },
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [
          {
            gridLines: {
              drawOnChartArea: false,
            },
            display: true,
            stacked: true,
          },
        ],
        yAxes: [
          {
            gridLines: {
              drawOnChartArea: false,
            },
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            },
            display: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataForFunnel();
  }

  getDataForFunnel() {
    this.barChartData = [];
    this.barChartLabels = [];
    this.currentResponseItems = [
      {
        Description: 'Prima Fase',
        Id: 49,
        Items: [
          { Id: -1, Description: 'Nessun Canale', Number: 7 },
          { Id: 5, Description: 'Altro Canale', Number: 3 },
          { Id: 21, Description: 'Collaboratore Enzo', Number: 1 },
        ],
      },
      {
        Description: 'Seconda Fase',
        Id: 70,
        Items: [
          { Id: -1, Description: 'Nessun Canale', Number: 3 },
          { Id: 3, Description: 'Web', Number: 3 },
          { Id: 5, Description: 'Altro Canale', Number: 3 },
          { Id: 27, Description: '15C', Number: 1 },
        ],
      },
    ];
    let array = [];
    this.currentResponseItems.forEach((x) => {
      array.push(x.Id);
    });
    this.currentResponseItems.forEach((y) => {
      this.barChartLabels.push(y.Description);
    });
    const colorMap = {};
    this.currentResponseItems.forEach((x) => {
      x.Items.forEach((z) => {
        if (!colorMap[z.Description]) {
          colorMap[z.Description] = getRandomRgb();
        }
        z['phaseId'] = x.Id;
        let zData = [];
        let number = array.indexOf(z.phaseId);
        if (z.Number != 0) {
          zData[number] = z.Number;
          console.log(colorMap[z.Description]);
          this.barChartData.push({
            data: zData,
            stack: x.Id,
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            grouped: true,
            label: z.Description,
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs-xue3ap)